# How to add if condition inside render function of jquery datatable

Tags: javascript, datatables

I want to add an if condition inside the render function of the column of jquery datatables

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#wfDefinitionGrid").DataTable({
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            "ajax": {
                "url": "@Url.Action("GetAllWfDefinitions", "WorkflowDefinition", new { area = "DXAdmin" })",
                "type": "POST",
                "datatype": "json"
            },

            "columns": [
                { "data": "Name", "name": "Name" }, 
                { "data": "Description", "name": "Description" },
                {
                    "render": function (data, type, full, meta) {
                        return '<div class="action_button">' +

                    if (@Model.AssnAppRoleModulePermissionModel.Select(s => s.PermissionKey).Contains(EnumHelper.GetDescription(PermissionType.EditWf))) 
{
                        '<img src="@Url.Content("~/images/edit.svg")" title="Edit" onclick="javascript: EditWfDefinition(' + full.WfDefinitionId + ');" />'
                    } + 

                    '<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="inactiveWorkflowDefinition"  onclick="ChangeStatus(' + full.WfDefinitionId + ',' + full.IsObsolete + ')">' + 
                    (full.IsObsolete == false ? '<img src="/images/Inactivate.svg" class="radioImgCls" title="Activate"/>' : '<img src="/images/Active.svg" class="radioImgCls" title="Inactivate" />') + 
                    '</a>' +
                    '<img src="@Url.Content("~/images/delete.svg")" title="Delete" onclick="javascript: DeleteWfDefinition(' + full.WfDefinitionId + ');" /></div>';
                }
            }
        ],          
    });
});
```

expected result should be like if the condition is true the whole img tag containing edit.svg will be displayed.

> ///error: uncaught SyntaxError: unexpected token if

Comment: Check out with $.DataTable API

Comment: @afr0 hello can u clarify it in details. apparently i'm new to the datatables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//for example if you want to add conditions to name Column    
    var columnDefs : [{ targets: "name",
    render : function(data, type, row){
    if(data !== 'undefined'){
        return data;
    }else{
        return 'NA';
    }
 ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem has nothing to do with datatable rendering a function with an if statement but with your condition being in Razor, the code won't compile inside a javascript condition.

You can try putting your condition in a variable and then compare in your if statement.

```
    var someVariable = "@Model.AssnAppRoleModulePermissionModel.Select(s => s.PermissionKey).Contains(EnumHelper.GetDescription(PermissionType.EditWf))"

    if (someVariable == "True"){
        //Do something
    } else {
        //Do something else
    }
```

**EDIT:**

Keep in mind that this piece of code won't work on a separate Javascript file since it's using Razor to obtain a value. You must always use the script tag in a `.cshtml` file.